# If something can convert to string in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have an SQL table and I want to convert it using C#.
I want to do something like this:

```
if (obj.pid is string)
{ /*action*/ }
```

but because it's an object from the table it can't see whether it is string or not.
How can I write something like that?

Comment: `GetType().IsAssignableFrom()`?

Comment: "_because it's an object from the table it can't see whether it is string or not_". Could you elaborate? If obj.pid is a string stored in an object reference, the `is` operator as used _will_ see that it is. That's sort of what it's for :)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sorry, but what should I write for it's arguments

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks you're right! :)

Comment: How this question gets an upvote, is something that puzzles me greatly. There are not many less-explained and less-researched questions in stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that obj.pid isn't a string, but an object, then you can do this:

```
 string pid = obj.pid as string;

  if (pid != null)
  {
    // Do something
  }
```

The `as` operator returns null if the object can't be converted to a string.

EDIT

I think I missunderstood you, I hope this is the solution:

It checks if the type of the object was a string before being stored as an object.

```
Type type = obj.pid.GetType();

if (type.Equals(typeOf(string)))
{
  // Do something
}
```

[Source: MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have a pid like 450546

Comment: and some of them are like alex

Comment: i want it to acknowledge the difference but it works as if all of them are string

Comment: so you want it to act in a certain way if it was a string? And pid is an object?

Comment: so I added something in the end I think will solve your problem if I understood you correctly. Try to work on your formulation, this will help others to help you... :) Watch edit 2

Comment: Type just means of what type the object/variable is. It well get the most accurate representation if you use object.GetType()